# OpenCL and Java

Tags: java, opencl

I've read about [OpenCL](http://developer.amd.com/zones/java/aparapi/Pages/default.aspx) lately and there is a library in Java that will allow the use of OpenCL. At to what extent that OpenCL and be used with Java. Also, is there any way that JVM can automatically offload process in the GPU transparently in the Java code.

One application would be with Java-to-Javascript compilers which can't use OpenCL directly, but its VM that do the translation can use the parallel processing perhaps?

Comment: In the tests I have done with these tools, they work with some coding overhead.  The problem I had is that it took quite some time to warm up, long enough that it was quicker to use the CPU. Obviously YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. Since the JVM is not built to recognize parallelism.

The longer answer is that you can do it with relatively few effort. At www.jocl.org you can find a JAR file which enables OpenCL support in Java, as well as some tutorials how to do this. If you have a fairly simple loop body in your Java code that is your bottleneck, there's a good chance OpenCL would give a nice improvement. I've often found an improvement x10 or larger, but this depends on your GPU. Differences over x100 have been reported.

It is not "integrated" in java though, you write the loop body in a .cl file and execute it from your main Java files. On the bright side, some IDEs (such as Netbeans) have OpenCL editor plugins on the web, which makes everything *look* more integrated. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look at [Aparapi](http://code.google.com/p/aparapi/). It allows you writing your OpenCL kernels in java. These are converted to real OpenCL code behind the screens. The largest advantage wrt using OpenCL binding is that your kernels are plain java so you can just use all the regular tools (ex. debugger, JUnit, IDE, ...). The project is being developed by AMD but it is still young.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4409) have OpenCL bindings. However it doesn't provide such a deep integration with the language or VM as I think you would like to have.

Another library that provides OpenCL bindings is [JOCL](http://jocl.org/).